# How can I resolve the following errors?: Error CS1022 and Error CS0116

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an API in C # with Visual Studio Code and a database in SQL Server and I get the following errors and don't know how to solve them:

> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,12): error CS0116: Un espacio de nombres no puede contener directamente miembros como campos o métodos. [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,33): error CS0116: Un espacio de nombres no puede contener directamente miembros como campos o métodos. [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,31): error CS1022: Se esperaba una definición de tipo o espacio de nombres, o el fin del archivo [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,43): error CS1022: Se esperaba una definición de tipo o espacio de nombres, o el fin del archivo [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(17,1): error CS1022: Se esperaba una definición de tipo o espacio de nombres, o el fin del archivo [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> ERROR al compilar.
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,12): error CS0116: Un espacio de nombres no puede contener directamente miembros como campos o métodos. [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,33): error CS0116: Un espacio de nombres no puede contener directamente miembros como campos o métodos. [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,31): error CS1022: Se esperaba una definición de tipo o espacio de nombres, o el fin del archivo [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(7,43): error CS1022: Se esperaba una definición de tipo o espacio de nombres, o el fin del archivo [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
>
> C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\Controllers\MedicineController.cs(17,1): error CS1022: Se esperaba una definición de tipo o espacio de nombres, o el fin del archivo [C:\Users\OD 36651\Desktop\web_api_proyectoFinal\web_api_db\web_api_db.csproj]
> 0 Advertencia(s)
> 5 Errores

This would be the C# code of connection to the database made in SQL Server (I don't know if this information will help but the database is in the cloud):

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;

namespace web_api_db.Models
{
    class Conexion : DbContext 
    {
        public Conexion(DbContextOption<Conexion> options) : base (options) {}

        public Dbset<Medicine> Medicine { get; set; }
    }

    class Conectar
    {
        private const cadenaConexion = "Server=dbClinica.mssql.somee.com;Database=dbClinica;User Id=munoz437_SQLLogin_1;Password=*****;";

        public static Conexion Create()
        {
            var constructor = new DbContextOptionBuilder<Conexion>();
            constructor.UseSqlServer(cadenaConexion);
            var cn = new Conexion (constructor.Options);
            return cn;
        }
    }
}
```

This would be the controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using web_api_db.Models;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
namespace web_api_db.Controllers
{
    public MedicineController : Controller
    {
        private Conexion dbConexion;

        public MedicineController()
        {
            dbConexion = Conectar.Create();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(dbConexion.Medicine.ToArray());
        }
    }  
}
```

This is my entity class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data;

namespace web_api_db.Models
{
    public class Medicine 
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }  
        public float price { get; set; }
        public string mark { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public int stocks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the Medicine Controller be inheriting from the ApiController rather than the Controller class !!

Comment: I see you use inner class `Conectar` to create `Conexion`. So, it should be ` dbConexion=Conexion.Conectar.Create();`.

Comment: Thanks @LeVu for seeing that error, I already corrected it but it gives me the following error: "error CS1001: A handle was expected". In the next line: ' private const cadenaConexion = "Server=dbClinica.mssql.somee.com; Database=dbClinica;User Id=munoz437_SQLLogin_1; password=6xr5piikj2"; '

Comment: @moya you're missing here the `string` datatype, so it should be `private const string cadenaConexion = "your connection string"`

Comment: It's true, thank you

Comment: @Moya my advice, you should remove or mask sensitive data before post it in a public place event if the DB server is a fake one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a compiler error in `MedicineController`.

The following decoration

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

Should be right above the controller class, not above the namespace.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using web_api_db.Models;

namespace web_api_db.Models
{
   [Route("api/[controller]")] 
   [ApiController]
   public MedicineController :ControllerBase
   {
      //... your controller body
   }
}
```

API controller should drive from `ControllerBase` as described in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#controllerbase-class)

> Don't create a web API controller by deriving from the Controller class. `Controller` derives from `ControllerBase` and adds support for views, so it's for handling web pages, not web API requests.There's an exception to this rule: if you plan to use the same controller for both views and web APIs, derive it from `Controller`

#### Best practices advice

Not related with the error, but it is really important

**Dependency injection**

Don't create the `dbConexion` object directly in the controller because it will consume memory and bade performance, instead try to use the dependency injection.

In `appsetting.json` file, add the following section

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
      "DefaultConnection": "<your connection string goes here!>"
},
```

Impotent information, you should never ever share the connection string with anyone because it has your database credentials.

Then register `Conexion` with dependency container in `Startup.cs` file in `ConfigureServices` method, add the following line

```
//... 
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      // configure EnityframeworkCore with SQL Server
      services.AddDbContext<Conexion>(op => {
          op.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
      });

      //... rest of method
}
//...
```

Then use the dependency injection in your `MedicineController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using web_api_db.Models;

namespace web_api_db.Models
{
   [Route("api/[controller]")] 
   [ApiController]
   public MedicineController :ControllerBase
   {
      private readonly Conexion dbConexion;

      public MedicineController(Conexion db)
      {
         dbConexion = db;
      }

      //... your actions
   }
}
```

**Async programming**

A database query will block the thread until the database response, so you should use asynchronous calling in your action like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

// .....
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
{
    return Ok(await dbConexion.Medicine.ToArrayAsync());
}
```

## Final result

Your `MedicineController` will look like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using web_api_db.Models;

namespace web_api_db.Models
{
   [Route("api/[controller]")] 
   [ApiController]
   public MedicineController : ControllerBase
   {
      private readonly Conexion dbConexion;

      public MedicineController(Conexion db)
      {
         dbConexion = db;
      }
    
      [HttpGet]
      public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
      {
         return Ok(await dbConexion.Medicine.ToArrayAsync());
      }
   }
}
```